# correctly import Kaggle dataset into R

Tags: r, quote, kaggle, read.csv

I was trying to use R to analyze the https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube-new/ dataset. The csv file opens fine in Excel, but cannot be loaded correctly into R using

```
data <- read.csv(
    "USvideos.csv", 
    header=TRUE, 
    sep = ",", 
    row.names = NULL, 
    quote = "\"")
```

It turns out that there are `"` characters within the quote in a column, and there are new line characters within the quote in a column as well.

Is there a way to let R figure out that the first and the last `"` character is the only quote character and ignore all the " characters and new line characters in the csv file as the Excel did?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If it opens properly in excel, have you tried converting it to xls/xlsx and then reading it into R?

Comment: this could work, however, there are a lot of datasets in Kaggle, if each one of them has to be converted by Excel, the Kaggle platform would be quite inefficient.

Comment: I tried the fread function as well, it does not work either ...

Comment: For me it's working `df <- read.csv("USvideos.csv", header=T)`. Can you try this and let us know (using `dput(header(df)`) what you get after executing this?

Comment: I have seen people analyzing this dataset by Python, is it just the problem of R?

Comment: I tried Prem's code, but it gives "In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string"

Comment: How about this? `df <- read.csv("USvideos.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, quote="", fill=F)`. BTW I am really not sure why it's giving error in your case (I used data from [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube-new/data) location). I suspect that your file might have corrupted so you may need to download a fresh copy and try again.

Comment: I downloaded the file as well. No problems importing it. May be a problem with your copy of the file as @Prem said

Comment: I download the file again, and used @Prem 's code, but I get: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 7 did not have 11 elements

Comment: is it because I am using the RStudio and there are some settings that I should make?

Comment: I find that if I do "data <- read.csv("USvideos.csv", quote="\"", header = TRUE)", the "EOF within quoted string" warning still exists. However, if I then do "summary(as.numeric(data$views))", the values can be analyzed, which means the data is loaded fine. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I've [written a quick kernel to double check the data](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/read-data-into-r/). It reads in fine with base R, but does throw some warnings when you try to read it in as a tibble. It still seems to load in more or less fine, though.

As a note, some of your read.csv() arguments are just the default for that argument (like quote) so I just omitted them. The very bottom example uses your exact syntax and works fine, though, so I'm not sure where you're running into trouble.

Comment: thanks for writing this kernel! The issue is that the first a few rows are fine, but if you do tail(data) or summary(data$views), the result is a mess ...

Comment: I've done some more digging and it looks like I'm not able to reproduce your errors. ([See the bottom of the notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/read-data-into-r/). I'm a little stumped... maybe try updating R or the packages you're using? I guess it could also be smart quotes... Did you open your .csv in Excel or something like that before R?

Comment: Thank you Rachael! I updated the R and the packages, the issue remains the same, is it because of the RStudio (is there any settings that should be done with the smart quotes?)?

Comment: It's possible that some of the quotes protecting the text have been replaced with smart quotes, which won't be interpreted correctly. If you've just downloaded the file & are loading it in it shouldn't be a problem. At this point, I'd ask in https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: I find that if I do "data <- read.csv("USvideos.csv", quote="\"", header = TRUE)", the "EOF within quoted string" warning still exists. However, if I then do "summary(as.numeric(data$views))", the values can be analyzed, which means the data is loaded fine. Thanks again!